# How to send simple information in headers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, session

I create an function to create a session expiry date, like below:

```
    @Override
    public Long sessionTime() throws ErrorException{
        Long expirySession = System.currentTimeMillis() + expirationTime;
        return expirySession;
    }
```

she is launch after every request and save this time in database,

but i must to send this time in all headers from my request in controller,

can somebody tell me how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Response entity headers

```
@GetMapping("/response-entity")
public ResponseEntity<String> usingResponseEntityBuilderAndHttpHeaders() {
    HttpHeaders responseHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    responseHeaders.set("sessionTime" ,sessionTime());
    return ResponseEntity.ok()
      .headers(responseHeaders)
      .body("ResponseEntity");
}
```

For more details check out https://www.baeldung.com/spring-response-header

Comment: Ok, but i don't want implement this in every of my 50 controllers, i need a globally solution

Comment: can i for example use this (without ```return```) in my ```sessionTime()``` function which is launch on every request?

Comment: @piotrek you can extend the OncePerRequestFilter  https://www.techiedelight.com/add-custom-header-to-all-responses-spring-boot/

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in Filter to have a generic handler for that feature in one place.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/package-summary.html

You need to implement `doFilter` method in this way:

```
public class Example implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;
        response .addHeader("header_name", "header_value");
        filterChain.doFilter(servletRequest, response);
    }

}
```